# HttpWebRequest GetRequestStream timeout on Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, android, json, post, xamarin

The following code runs perfectly and returns data immediately in a Wpf test application but hangs on request.GetRequestStream() in Xamarin Android:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Accept = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";

string postData = "{}";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    sw.Write(postData);

var response = request.GetResponse();

using (var sw = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = sw.ReadToEnd();
}
```

No code change between the apps, copy and paste. Any ideas?

Edit: I do have another section of code that uses ChannelFactory to connect to a different wcf service. That code works and returns data to the app. This url is for a service hosting RESTful/JSON contracts. The Internet permission is checked.

Comment: do you have solved to problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dispose your response, otherwise it will only take a couple of requests before you potentially start queueing in .NET code.

```
// **snip**
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = sw.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
// **snip**
```

Comment: he says the GetRequestStream is hanging, not the response

Comment: True, my statement should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I will keep in mind the disposing. I mostly just wanted to see it work. I added an edit comment that it does work over the internet in other ways.